# Unhandled Exception:System.NotImplementedException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: xamarin.forms, accelerometer, sensors, sensormanager

I want to use the accelerometer Sensor in my app (xamarin.forms). I am also using files from another project that should work, so that why I dont know why I get an Exception Error

```
public static IDeviceSensors Current
        {
            get
            {
                IDeviceSensors ret = implementation.Value;
                if (ret == null)
                {
                    **throw NotImplementedInReferenceAssembly();**
                }
                return ret;
            }
        }
```

Did I missed out anything ?

Comment: You need implement your assembly from another project for use them. You can [look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) here

Comment: @Batuhan I used: [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Exception))] in my MainActivity.cs now and it works now thanks :)